# How to copy and paste a filtered table using VBA from one column to another visible column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have trouble in solving this particular issue .
I am currently trying to automate a function where the macro would automatically update a value from Column C to Column D

For example if in filtered Cell C2 and C4 have a value i would like it to paste to Cell D2 and D4 and would skip D3

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope my explanation makes sense , as this is a sample i can think of in explaining on larger scale

Comment: Why do you need a macro - wouldn't an IF formula suffice?

Comment: Are you talking about that two cells, or about all visible cells of the two involved cells? If the last supposition, using VBA you should use `SpecialCells((xlCellTypeVisible))` and must understand that such a range is **composed of areas**. So, you should iterate between each area element and copy it in the corresponding column cell.

Comment: This is an basic explanation one on a problem on my main project ,in the main project Column D will be populated from Column B and Column C together as Class 1 ,2 and 3.
The thing is Column B have a value in row 1 and row 3 while Column 3 have a value in row 2 and row 4

Comment: So, don't you need/want copying from the **visible cells range**? If not, **based on what** to make VBA knowing that you want copying from B (rows 1 and 3) and from C (rows 2 and 4)?

Comment: It is not possible to copy non conitous ranges to other non conitous ranges. You need to copy each area one after another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy the filtered cells of column "C:C" (starting from the second row), to the corresponding rows of column "D:D":

```
Sub copyVisCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngVS As Range, Ar As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rngVS = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'here it needs error checking in case of no visible cells...
  For Each Ar In rngVS.Areas
      Ar.Copy Ar.Offset(0, 1)
  Next Ar
End Sub
```

If you can define a rule based on what to copy values from B:B, let us say a row before the visible cells in D:D, the code can be adapted to do it, but you must explain **based on what rule** to do it...

Comment: Hi , thank you!
From this sample , I understand what need to alter and the code work wonderfully once I apply error checking